# MediaPlayer is not stop when application exit

Tags: java, android, media-player

I am very beginner in Android application. I am added MediaPlayer and it is playing correctly when application launches. I wanted to stop MediaPlayer being played in background if the user exit application before song completed. Kindly help me!!! Here is my code below

```
package com.example.myappname;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.animal_kit);
    mp.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();

    super.onDestroy();

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.animal_kit);
```

in this line you're creating another MediaPlayer variable instead of initializing your class's field. And a NullPointerException will be thrown in `onDestroy()` because `mp` field of your class is null.

just change the line to:

```
mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.animal_kit);
```